# assigning categoical values to multiple variables in r

Tags: r, variable-assignment, multiple-variable-return

Say I have the following data input into R

```
x <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0)
y <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0)
z <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
p <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)

data <- data.frame(x,y,z,p)
```

Now I want to introduce a new variable in data called 'cat'

within cat I want to assign 'a' values to any observation where 1 appears in either x or y o appears in both. I want to assign the value 'b' to observations where 1 appears in either/both of z and p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c("b", "a")[(!!rowSums(data[,1:2])) +0 + (!!rowSums(data[,3:4])+1)]
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
```

- Assuming that I understand the condition and also assuming that there won't be any intersecting cases i.e. rows of either or both `x`, `y` that are `1` doesn't have an intersect with `z` or `p` having `1` values
- As a first step, I did `rowSums` on columns `x` and `y`

  ```
  rowSums(data[,1:2])
  #[1] 2 1 1 0 0 0
  ```
- Double negation on the above result and adding `0` gives

  ```
  (!!rowSums(data[,1:2]))+0
   #[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0
  ```
- Same thing when applied to columns `z` and `p` but I add `1` gives

  ```
  (!!rowSums(data[,3:4]))+1
  #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
  ```
- If you add the above two results, will get

  ```
  (!!rowSums(data[,1:2])) +0 + (!!rowSums(data[,3:4])+1)
   #[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1
  ```
- This can be used as a numeric index so that if I use `c("b", "a")[!!rowSums..]`, the `2` values will be replaced by `b` and `1` with `a`.

Comment: Could use some elaboration / explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This line returns "a" if either `x` or `y` is non-zero, and "b" otherwise.

```
ifelse(data$x | data$y, "a", "b")
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
```

If you need to handle the case where all four columns are zero, you could use:

```
ifelse(data$x | data$y,
       "a",
       ifelse(data$z | data$p, "b", "neither a nor b"))
```

Comment: how does the 'ifelse' command work if my data is extended to three variables
such that
g <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
h <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
i <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
j <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
k <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
l <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

where i want to assign:
R where 1 occurs in either/both g and h
Q where 1 occurs in either/both i and j
S where 1 occurs in either/both k and l

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Perhaps you need another "or" (the vertical bar symbol)?